# Now does var_dump() get class function names?

Tags: php

```
class animal
{
  var $type;
  var $says;

  function __construct($_type)
  {
      $type = $_type;
  }

  function Does_he_think_hes_the_boss()
  {
      return ($type == 'cat');
  }  
} // animal

$dog = new animal('dog');

var_dump($dog);
```

gives

```
object(animal)[1]
  public 'type' => null
  public 'says' => null
```

I'd like to get as much info as I can about a class (for debugging porpoises) - names of variables, names of functions (with their signatures, if possible), parent class, if any, etc ...

How much info can I get from an object?

Comment: Uhm, it gives another output actually http://ideone.com/D9JAH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve all detailed information you need about object using [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Comment: @Mawg: 1) "There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core." (c) http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.installation.php 2) What if php itself is not installed? ;-)

Comment: +1 and a big "d'oh!" from me. I was in a rush for a meeting and looked at the manual and saw a link to "Installing/Configuring". I didn't follow it, just assumed soem install. This looks great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

```
function dump( $var ) {
    $result = var_export( $var, true );
    $loc = whereCalled();
    return "\n<pre>Dump: $loc\n$result</pre>";
}

function whereCalled( $level = 1 ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $file   = $trace[$level]['file'];
    $line   = $trace[$level]['line'];
    $object = $trace[$level]['object'];
    if (is_object($object)) { $object = get_class($object); }

    return "Where called: line $line of $object \n(in $file)";
}
```

Comment: am I missing something? Isn't that for the stack?

Comment: "I'd like to get as much info as I can about a class - names of variables, names of fucntions, parent class, if any, etc ..."